# php t_string error in loop

Tags: php, loops, input, textbox

I thought this code was okay but I am receiving the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" for this section of my program. Could anyone please tell me what I have done wrong? And if I have written the style part right?

Thanks.

```
    } elseif ($answers['answerType'] == "textbox"){
    echo ("\n<ul><input type=\"text\" id=\"text-$questionID\" value=\"$answer\"
    style="width:100px; height:40px"; <br /></ul>";
```

Comment: Consider adding more code. It is disconcerting to see a portion of a conditional block without the initial `if` statement. Also include any resources you tried already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You have not closed the input tag properly and inline style need to be wrapped `\`

```
 <input type=\"text\" id=\"text-$questionID\" value=\"$answer\"
style=\"width:100px; height:40px;\">
                                ---^
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't escape all `"` characters and didn't close `(` which you can ommit. Try with:

```
echo "\n<ul><input type=\"text\" id=\"text-$questionID\" value=\"$answer\"
      style=\"width:100px; height:40px\"; <br /></ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add slashes with all double quotes also a unwanted parenthesis 
try

```
echo "\n<ul><input type=\"text\" id=\"text-$questionID\" value=\"$answer\"
    style=\"width:100px; height:40px\"; <br /></ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

your echo line was incorrect. You have openned unwanted `(`  and didnt escape the `"`. So better use different inner quotes or use `HEREDOC`. so try this

```
echo "\n<ul><input type='text' id='text-$questionID' value='$answer' style='width:100px; height:40px'; <br /></ul>";
```